# How to autocomplete textbox with google maps api for only states of india?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to autocomplete my textbox with google api so that it only shows states of india. But i could not do this thing, my code is shown below -

```
            <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var optionState = {
                types: ['(administrative_area_level_1)'], 
                componentRestrictions: { country: "in" }
            };
            var stateInput = $('#<%= stateTextBox.ClientID %>')[0];
            var autocompleteState = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(stateInput, optionState);
            </script>
```

Please help - 
Below is the working code for autocomplete city textbox for all cities of india-

```
            var optionCity = {
                types: ['(cities)'],
                componentRestrictions: { country: "in" }
            };
            var cityInput = $('#<%= cityTextBox.ClientID %>')[0];
            var autocompleteCity = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(cityInput, optionCity);
```

My question is that if city is working then why can' the states?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing but with `administrative_area_level_1?`?

Comment: yes i tried by putting types: ['(administrative_area_level_1)'] but the autocomplete does not work though.

Comment: the type `administrative_area_level_1` is not supported by  the autocomplete, but there are not so many states in india, it shouldn't be very complicated to create a Autocomplete on your own (e.g. via jQueryUI)